How to integrate 'Around' logic in Dynamic Proxy Generation and conditionally call 'Before' and 'After'?
I have a project for Dynamic Proxy Generation with DLR using the following structure:
ProxyGenerator.cs
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshalling;

namespace ProxyGenerator
{
  public delegate void ProceedDelegate();

  class ProxyGenerator : DynamicMetaObject
  {
    private readonly IInterception interception;
    public ProxyGenerator(Expression expr, object obj, IInterception interception)
      : base(expr, BindingRestrictions.Empty, obj)
    {
      this.interception = interception;
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder)
    {
      return WeaveAspect(base.BindGetMember(binder));
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindSetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject value)
    {
      return WeaveAspect(base.BindSetMember(binder, value), value);
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] args)
    {
      return WeaveAspect(base.BindInvokeMember(binder, args), args);
    }

    private DynamicMetaObject WeaveAspect(DynamicMetaObject originalObj, params DynamicMetaObject[] args)
    {
      var originalExpr = originalObj.Expression;
      var originalValParam = Expression.Parameter(originalExpr.Type);

      var beforeExpr = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(interception),
        typeof(IInterception).GetMethod(nameof(IInterception.Before))!);
      var afterExpr = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(interception),
        typeof(IInterception).GetMethod(nameof(IInterception.After))!);


      var advicedExpr = Expression.Block(
        new[] { originalValParam },
        beforeExpr,
        Expression.Assign(originalValParam, originalExpr),
        afterExpr,
        originalValParam
      );

      var advicedObj = new DynamicMetaObject(
        advicedExpr,
        originalObj.Restrictions
      );

      return advicedObj;
    }
  }
}


IInterception.cs
namespace ProxyGenerator {
  interface IInterception {
    void Before();
    void After();
    object? Around(Delegate proceed, object[] args);
  }
}


LogInterception.cs
namespace ProxyGenerator {
  class LogInterception : IInterception {
    public void Before() {
      Console.WriteLine("^ before");
    }

    public void After() {
      Console.WriteLine("v after");
    }

    public object? Around(Delegate proceed, object[] args) {
      Console.WriteLine("{ around (before)");
      object? result = null;

      if (!args.Any() || args[0].Equals("gp")) {
        Console.WriteLine("> proceeding");

        result = proceed.DynamicInvoke();

        if (result != null && (int)result < 10)
          result = 10;
        Console.WriteLine("< proceeded");
      } else {
        Console.WriteLine("x not proceeding");
      }

      Console.WriteLine("} around (after)");
      return result;
    }
  }
}


Program.cs
using ProxyGenerator;

Test test = new();
test.DoSomething("gp", "is", "awesome");
test.DoSomething("this", "is", "madness");
Console.WriteLine($"number: {test.TestGetter}");

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
Console.WriteLine();

dynamic proxy = new Test();
proxy.DoSomething("gp", "is", "awesome");
proxy.DoSomething("this", "is", "madness");
Console.WriteLine($"number: {proxy.TestGetter}");

Console.WriteLine();

My question is: how can I modify the WeaveAspect method in order to integrate the logic of Around and ensure that Before and After are called only if allowed by Around?.
